# Building React views with Webpack from a Java server

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, webpack

I'm currently developing a front end app with React.js, using Webpack for the build. For the development process, I'm using Webpack Dev Server, which is fine for my own purposes. I have configured production Webpack builds from Node.js servers and am comfortable with how that works.

For this project, however, the server is being written in Java. How would one go about performing the Webpack build process in this environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having forgotten about this question for some time, I just looked at my profile and realized that I do know the answer. And the answer is:

### You Can't

Webpack is a Node.js process, and would need to be run on a Node.js server. Now, you'd actually probably be able to run a concurrent Node process just to build the front-end stuff with Webpack. The other option would be to throw React and your dependencies into whichever directory you're serving your JS scripts from.